# Where can I find the Java SDK in Linux after installing it?

Tags: linux, java

I installed JDK using apt-get install but I don't know where my jdk folder is. I need to set the path for that. Does any one have a clue on the location?

Comment: Linux Distribution : Debian 2.6.26

Comment: Try `/usr/local/java/` for original downloaded Oracle distributions.

Answer (score 456, accepted):

This depends a bit from your package system ... if the `java` command works, you can type `readlink -f $(which java)` to find the location of the java command. On the OpenSUSE system I'm on now it returns `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0/jre/bin/java` (but this is not a system which uses `apt-get`).

---

On Ubuntu, it [looks like it is in](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openjdk-6-jdk/filelist) `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/` for OpenJDK, and in some other subdirectory of `/usr/lib/jvm/` for Suns JDK (and other implementations as well, I think).

[Debian is the same.](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/i386/openjdk-6-jre/filelist)

---

For any given package you can determine what files it installs and where it installs them by querying dpkg.  For example for the package 'openjdk-6-jdk': `dpkg -L openjdk-6-jdk`

Comment: orth looking in /usr/java too on some setups I've seen

Comment: If you are to add the JDK path in android studio, add this
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/

Comment: It seems my path is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`.

Comment: I think readlink as given is most elegant (and efficient), but I suggest `readlink -f $(which javac)`  - note the 'c' in case there is a strange mix of JDK and JRE on the same machine. The JDK includes a compiler (javac) and a JRE does not. However if path is not correct, which will fail and you can try this: `find /usr/java -wholename '*ava/jdk*' -prune` as I note in a comment below.

Comment: @Winnemucca It works for me, you can find where java is and then you can find where jdk path.

Comment: in zoo.cfg file makesure you add the field  `initLimit=10` or `initLimit=20` , this will help in first place when you gonna start zookeper for first time

Comment: On Debian/Ubuntu if you have the `default-jdk` or `default-jre` packages installed, you can resolve the symbolic link `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` that will point to the default version installed JDK or JRE according with your OS version: `readlink -f /usr/lib/jvm/default-java`

Answer (score 56):

```
update-java-alternatives -l
```

will tell you which java implementation is the default for your system and where in the filesystem it is installed. Check the manual for more options.

Comment: This is debian specific (at least). Other distros may not have this

Comment: @dequis, it's an answer specific to debian, since the question mentioned `apt-get` and the distro to be `Debian 2.6.26`. AFAIK, it should be the same for all debian derivatives.

Comment: I'm just pointing it out for other people. I know it's valid for this particular question.

Comment: update-alternatives --list | grep java worked for me on RHEL

Answer (score 37):

```
$ which java
```

should give you something like

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: true. i bet it is after apt-get install

Comment: This does not actually point to a full JDK. 1. It is a symlink, and even if you read the symlink, the binary is also not within a  JDK. For example, if I run the command `readlink -f $(which javac)` it prints `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javac`. That bin folder is NOT a JDK. General acid-base test to see if its a JDK is to see if the current `$JAVA_HOME` contains a path of `lib/tools.jar` . In the cast of `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin` that is not true, therefore it is not a JDK.

Comment: On Centos / RHL This is what I prefer to find the JDK (if installed)

`find /usr/java -wholename '*ava/jdk*' -prune`

But behavior depends whether you are talking about  OpenJDK or Oracle Java and how it was installed in the first place.

Answer (score 13):

Use find to located it.  It should be under `/usr` somewhere:

```
find /usr -name java
```

When running the command, if there are too many "Permission denied" message obfuscating the actual found results then, simply redirect stderr to /dev/null

```
find /usr -name java 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: If not root (admin) you will get plenty of Permission Denied messages.

Answer (score 13):

This question will get moved but you can do the following

```
which javac
```

or

```
cd /
find . -name 'javac'
```

Comment: I like the second option - simple & useful if you have multiple JREs/JDKs and want to find them all.

Comment: "find / -name 'javac'" is less typing, but requires admin (root) privilege or you will get a lot permission denied messages.

Answer (score 8):

Another best way to find Java folder path is to use `alternatives` command in Fedora Linux (I know its for Ubuntu but I hit this post from google just by its headline). Just want to share incase people like me looking for answers for fedora flavour.

To display all information regarding java

```
alternatives --display java
```

Comment: This worked for me, returning /usr/java/jdk-[version] on Fedora

Answer (score 5):

Three Step Process:
First:
open Terminal->`$ whereis java`
it would give output like this:
`java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz`

Second:
`ls -l /usr/bin/java`
It would give output like this:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Feb  9 10:59 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java`

Third:
`ls -l /etc/alternatives/java`
output is the JDK path:
`lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Feb  9 10:59 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java`

Answer (score 3):

Simple, try it:

It's /**usr/local/java/jdk[version]**

Answer (score 3):

This question still seems relevant, and the answer seems to be a moving target.

On my debian system (buster):

```
> update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
```

However, if you actually go look there, you'll see there are multiple directories and symbolic links placed there by the package system to simplify future maintenance.

The actual directory is `java-11-openjdk-amd64`, with another symlink of `default-java`.  There is also an `openjdk-11` directory, but it appears to only contain a source.zip file.

Given this, for Debian ONLY, I would guess the best value to use is `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java`, as this should always be valid, even if you decide to install a totally different version of java, or even switch vendors.

The normal reason to want to know the path is because some application wants it, and you probably don't want that app to break because you did an upgrade that changed version numbers.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux Fedora30 several versions of the full java JDK are available, specifically package names:

```
java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 
java-11-openjdk-devel.x86_64
```

Once installed, they are found in: `/usr/lib/jvm`

To select the location/directory of a full development JDK (which is different from the simpler runtime only JRE) look for entries:

```
ls -ld java*openjdk*
```

Here are two good choices, which are links to specific versions, where you will have to select the version:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk
```

Answer (score 3):

below command  worked in my `debain 10` box!

```
root@debian:/home/arun# readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

Answer (score 2):

the command: `sudo update-alternatives --config java` will find the complete path of all installed Java versions

Answer (score 0):

on OpenSUSE 13.1/13.2 its: `/usr/lib64/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-(version-number)`
version-number can be 1.7.x 1.8.x etc. check software manager witch version you have installed...

André

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way which worked for me 
Execute this Command:-

```
$(dirname $(readlink $(which javac)))/java_home
```