# How do I find out what keystore my JVM is using?

Tags: java, jvm, keytool

I need to import a certificate into my JVM keystore. I am using the following:

```
keytool -import -alias daldap -file somecert.cer
```

so I would need to probably change my call into something like:

```
keytool -import -alias daldap -file somecert.cer -keystore cacerts –storepass changeit
```

Comment: You need to import a certificate into your JVM *truststore,* unless its a signed CSR, in which case you should be importing it into your *own* keystore, and you must already know where that is, otherwise you wouldn't have been able to generate the keypair or the CSR.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Your keystore will be in your `JAVA_HOME---> JRE -->lib---> security--> cacerts`.  You need to check where your JAVA_HOME is configured, possibly one of these places,

1. Computer--->Advanced --> Environment variables---> JAVA_HOME
2. Your server startup batch files.

In your import command -keystore cacerts (give full path to the above JRE here instead of just saying cacerts).

Comment: /Library/Java/Home/lib/security/cacerts on Mac OS X 10.9

Comment: * "JAVA_HOME---> JRE -->lib---> security--> cacerts"

Note the "s" at the end, just for any future readers.

Comment: So if I install a new version of Java, and JAVA_HOME is pointing to a new directory, am I going to have certificate issues?

Comment: @KirillYunussov: If you have installed any certs to old JRE, then you need to import same certs to new JRE too.

Comment: How to check JAVA_HOME for linux machine ?

Comment: @Murphy : This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251323/where-can-i-find-the-java-sdk-in-linux

Comment: this is trust store location rather than key store location I think.

Comment: /usr/lib/jvm/<jvm-version>/jre/lib/security/cacerts on Ubuntu and other Debian-based systems

Comment: On Ubuntu, running `echo $JAVA_HOME` with root prints me nothing.

Answer (score 51):

**Keystore Location**

Each keytool command has a `-keystore` option for specifying the name and location of the persistent keystore file for the keystore managed by keytool. The keystore is by default stored in a file named `.keystore` in the user's home directory, as determined by the "user.home" system property. Given user name uName, the "user.home" property value defaults to

```
C:\Users\uName on Windows 7 systems
C:\Winnt\Profiles\uName on multi-user Windows NT systems
C:\Windows\Profiles\uName on multi-user Windows 95 systems
C:\Windows on single-user Windows 95 systems
```

Thus, if the user name is "cathy", "user.home" defaults to

```
C:\Users\cathy on Windows 7 systems
C:\Winnt\Profiles\cathy on multi-user Windows NT systems
C:\Windows\Profiles\cathy on multi-user Windows 95 systems
```

https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/keytool.html#importing-a-certificate-for-the-ca

Comment: I've been searching for this mystery `~/.keystore` file! If I left off the `-keystore` parameter, I couldn't figure out which default keystore `keytool` targeting. I kept looking for other `cacerts` somewhere else on the machine. I didn't expect keytool to generate `~/.keystore` in the home directory, nor for it to be named `.keystore` instead of `cacerts`. You've filled in a blank that the Java folks should document! Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

Mac OS X 10.12 with Java 1.8:

$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security

```
cd $JAVA_HOME
```

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home

From there it's in:

```
./jre/lib/security
```

I have a cacerts keystore in there.

To specify this as a VM option:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

I'm not saying this is the correct way (Why doesn't java know to look within JAVA_HOME?), but this is what I had to do to get it working.

Answer (score 24):

You can find it in your "Home" directory:

On Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_ACCOUNT>\.keystore
```

On Linux (Ubuntu):

```
/home/<YOUR_ACCOUNT>/.keystore
```

Comment: i don't have this directory on windows

Comment: I did a -keygen without specifying a keystore, expecting it to create one in the current directory, but it created it in my home as you said.
~/.keystore

Couldn't find it for ages! :-)
Thanks.

Comment: let me add that under cygwin the windows path is used since the java property `user.home` is equal to `$HOMEDRIVE$HOMEPATH` set by windows and not on `$HOME` set by cygwin where `HOMEDRIVE=C:` and `HOMEPATH=\Users\[YOUR ACCOUNT]`

Comment: Are you 100pct sure ***JVM*** does read these?

Comment: this isn't true on my ubuntu

Answer (score 18):

This works for me:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

CACERTS=$(readlink -e $(dirname $(readlink -e $(which keytool)))/../lib/security/cacerts)

if keytool -list -keystore $CACERTS -storepass changeit > /dev/null ; then
    echo $CACERTS
else
    echo 'Can not find cacerts file.' >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Only for Linux. My Solaris has no readlink. In the end I used this Perl-Script:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd qw(realpath);
$_ = realpath((grep {-x && -f} map {"$_/keytool"} split(':', $ENV{PATH}))[0]);
die "Can not find keytool" unless defined $_;
my $keytool = $_;
print "Using '$keytool'.\n";
s/keytool$//;
$_ = realpath($_ . '../lib/security/cacerts');
die "Can not find cacerts" unless -f $_;
my $cacerts = $_;
print "Importing into '$cacerts'.\n";
`$keytool -list -keystore "$cacerts" -storepass changeit`;
die "Can not read key container" unless $? == 0;
exit if $ARGV[0] eq '-d';
foreach (@ARGV) {
    my $cert = $_;
    s/\.[^.]+$//;
    my $alias = $_;
    print "Importing '$cert' as '$alias'.\n";
    `keytool -importcert -file "$cert" -alias "$alias" -keystore "$cacerts" -storepass changeit`;
    warn "Can not import certificate: $?" unless $? == 0;
}
```

Comment: This helped me to find a new key store that I wasn't aware of. Thank you

Answer (score 13):

On Debian, using openjdk version "1.8.0_212", I found cacerts here:

```
 /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Sure would be handy if there was a standard command that would print out this path.

Comment: this is the path too in Alpine Linux - `keytool -list -cacerts` to show the certs

Answer (score 7):

As DimtryB mentioned, by default the keystore is under the user directory. But if you are trying to update the `cacerts` file, so that the JVM can pick the keys, then you will have to update the `cacerts` file under `jre/lib/security`. You can also view the keys by executing the command `keytool -list -keystore cacerts` to see if your certificate is added.

Comment: Nice to know that the keytool command adds the correct `lib/security` path automatically if given only the relative name.

Comment: But this will not work for `-importcert`. The list command shows the system wide certificates but the import command generates a new file in the current directory.

Comment: `updatedb; locate cacerts` helps for finding where the install locations of th e cacerts files are.

Answer (score 5):

For me using the [official OpenJDK 12 Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk), the location of the Java keystore was:

```
/usr/java/openjdk-12/lib/security/cacerts
```

Comment: That's a truststore, not a keystore.

Comment: First: If you read the question carefully (and your own comment), it sounds more like a Truststore, where a cert should be imported. Second, the difference between the Truststore and Keystore is quite disorienting - and both use the term "Keystore" btw, since they use the format both. Third: If you have a look at the import command `keytool -import -file example.crt -alias exampleCA -keystore truststore.jks` you also use the parameter `-keystore`... quite unclear IMHO. And last but not least: I was searching about that exact problem - and found that so question. Maybe others exp the same.

Comment: Furthermore all other answers also refer to the so called "Truststore" the JDK uses to validate. So did you also downvote all the other answers as well? I already received an upvote, so there's already somebody my answer helped out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the JVM keystore using the following command on Ubuntu 20.04:

```bash
echo $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/lib/security/cacerts
```

This directory is a symbolic link to:

```
/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this issue on a Tomcat running from a jre directory that was (almost fully) removed after an automatic jre update, so that the running jre could no longer find jre.../lib/security/cacerts because it no longer existed.

Restarting Tomcat (after changing the configuration to run from the different jre location) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all answers above:

If updating the cacerts file in JRE directory doesn't help, try to update it in JDK.

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_192\jre\lib\security**