# How do I find out what truststore file a Java VM has actually loaded?

Tags: java, file, keystore

How do I programatically find what java keystore file my JVM's default TrustManager is using?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using) is similar, but the answers are all actually about which keystore file it *should* be using.  I want to display in my program the actual keystore file that the JVM *has* loaded.

Update: Question: 'why don't I know? answer is my application is running on customer environments I don't control, so I dont know.

Update: Question: 'There is no default keystore, but there is a default truststore': I've updated my question.  I'm trying to learn the keystores in use by the default truststore.

Update: The impetus behind this question is I want to dispay in my app what keystore needs updating.  The admin operating the application often has trouble determining the correct jvm in use, let alone the correct keystore.  I want to give a clue to the admin what keystore they need to be updating.  Yes I know the admin 'should' know a lot of things about java and keys that they probably do not.

Comment: Why don't you already know? Unless you've created and initialized your own `KeyManager`, it can only be whatever is given by the `java.net.ssl.keyStore` system property.

Comment: @amb refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html), but has rightly said that you should now what you have configured.

Comment: @ankur-singhal How exactly does the Javadoc for KeyStore help with identifying the keystore? There are no methods that tell you where the contents came from.

Comment: Not only that, but one JVM can use more than one keystore, even millions, each from a different file or not from any file at all (such as but not limited to PKCS#11). There is one truststore file and *optionally* one keystore file (often different) used *by default for SSL or HTTPS connections*, and you can find those with a little effort, but they can be replaced or modified by code. If you want to know what file you're using the simplest approach is to explicitly use a file you know.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 There is a default truststore, but there is no default keystore at all.

Comment: @EJP there is the sysprop is set, that's what I meant by 'optionally'. In some of the environments I use sysprop values are configured in numerous places, some well hidden, which for practical purposes are defaults even though they aren't done directly by the JVM.

Comment: Re your edit: 'I'm trying to learn the keystores in use by the default truststore': There are no default keystores in use by the default truststore. Truststores don't use keystores. The updated question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I programatically find what java keystore file my JVM's default TrustManager is using?

It is given by the content of `javax.net.ssl.trustManager,` if set, otherwise it is the `lib/security/jssecacerts` file in the JRE folder if present, otherwise it is the `lib/security/cacerts` file.

This is all specified in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

> The impetus behind this question is I want to dispay in my app what keystore needs updating.

I don't know why you think a Java-supplied truststore file would need updating, but you're mistaken, unless you're dealing with self-signed certificates, in which case the real answer is "don't".

Comment: This answer is helpful, but still doesn't answer the actual question.  This shows what file it should be using, not a way to tell what it actually did load.

Comment: To address the last part of this answer:  In this case yes there are self-signed certs involved, but this software is typically used inside the firewall on non-web protocols so self-signed certs are the norm, right or wrong it doesn't matter and is irrelevent to the question.

Comment: @amb Your question was, and I quote, 'How do I find out what truststore file a Java VM has actually loaded?', and again 'How do I programatically find what java keystore file my JVM's default TrustManager is using?', and that is what I answered. And self-signed certificates are most certainly not the norm.