# Grails mail Exchange server configuration

Tags: email, grails, smtp

I'm trying to configure mail with an Exchange server.

This is my configuration

```
grails {
    mail {
        host = "mail.xxx.xx.xx"
        port = 443
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
        props = [   "mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                    "mail.smtp.port":"443",
                    "mail.smtp.ssl.enable" :"true"
                 ]
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Message: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Connection reset. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
```

I know it's an issue with the props that I have to change, since this configuration works on my mail app.
I know that the port is correct, it uses SSL.

I also tried using these props

```
    props = ["mail.smtp.timeout"               : "100000",
             "mail.smtp.starttls.enable"       : "true",
             "mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable"      : "true",
             "mail.transport.protocol"         : "smtps",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port"    : "443",
             "mail.smtp.auth"                  : "true",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class"   : "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback": "false",
             "mail.debug"                      : "true"]
```

The debug result it this  :

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.1
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "xxx.xxx.xx.xx", port 443, isSSL true
```

Comment: As you are using SSL, are you sure your java keystore has CA for the issuer of the certificate of the server?

Comment: No, can you explain to me more how to do this ? what i did is only add the data from my mail app to this configuration.

Comment: Could you try what I said?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as a certificate problem. If you have access to a server not using SSL, I would test that first, otherwise you should:

- Find the certificate issuer (If you don't know it, you could use openssl verify http://www.herongyang.com/Cryptography/OpenSSL-Certificate-Path-Validation-Tests.html)
- Look a CA in your java keystore

  - Locate Either the default java keystore ([How do I find out what keystore my JVM is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using)) or the one you are using
  - List the keystore and look for a corresponding CA
  - If there is a CA then the problem is not likely to be this
  - If there is no corresponding CA, then obtain the CA certificate and import it to you keystore, restart the server, and should work again.

Comment: Hi tried it, it's not a certificate issue, because i have it.

Comment: Uhm, are you sure your port is 443? Normally that port is used by secure web servers. The standard port for secure smtp is 465.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue a while back. If you are trying to access an exchange server within a network (organization), I believe the port number is the issue here. It could have been changed by the network admin.

Please contact the network administrator and explain to him that you are trying to access the Exchange Server and require the username, password and the relevant port number. Authentication could be optional if the app is run in-house, i.e.

`props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"false"]`

I hope this helps.