# Update Android app build on Titanium Appcelerator into Native app, sign certificate issue

Tags: android, google-play, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I've developed my app 3 years ago on Titanium Appcelerator platform. I didn't use custom JKS for signing. Titaniume gave me ready APK and I uploaded it to Google Play, during 3 years I did 10 updates without problems.

Now I developed native Android App with the same package name. But I cannot find ".jks" file for signing. Without it Google Play will not accept as an update. How can I find that file for sign?

Answer (score 1):

@Nambari does a good job of answering your question regarding "How can I find that file for sign?" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using).

Additionally, consider reviewing any backups you have made during the previous 10 updates you did to see if your keystore was saved during that process.