# Maven error, PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven

There are two remote servers are presents. Supposed we named them as a A and B.
My java code is committed and up to date on GIT repository.
I pulled the code on both server A and B. When I use mvn clean package install on server A, its working properly and build get successfully completed.
But When I use mvn clean package install for server B its giving me following error with build failure massage.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] oagi-srt ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.292 s]
[INFO] oagi-srt-common .................................... SUCCESS [  1.959 s]
[INFO] oagi-srt-repository ................................ SUCCESS [  2.357 s]
[INFO] oagi-srt-service ................................... SUCCESS [  2.064 s]
[INFO] oagi-srt-import .................................... SUCCESS [  3.064 s]
[INFO] oagi-srt-webapp .................................... FAILURE [ 21.398 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.539 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-10T11:50:10+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 44M/303M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project srt-webapp: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.oagi:srt-webapp:war:1.0.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.joinfaces:jsf-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.7 -> org.primefaces.extensions:all-themes:jar:1.0.8 -> org.primefaces.themes:afterdark:jar:1.0.8: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.primefaces.themes:afterdark:jar:1.0.8: Could not transfer artifact org.primefaces.themes:themes-project:pom:1.0.8 from/to prime-repo-new (http://repository.primefaces.org): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :srt-webapp
```

Note:-If i directly place project **war file** in tomcat and restart the server, my application is working properly as I expected on both server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your B server does not have the certificates to access the repository, try to compare the environment certificates between servers A and B.

Also check this question: [How do I find out what keystore my JVM is using?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using)

Comment: Thank you Luis, your suggestion help me a lot. I cross check the certificate environment and some of the certificates are not present on server B.

Answer (score 33):

My company IT policies blocked maven repo https because the certificate expired date is short.
Importing certificate is painful. So I used this way to fix it:

- change to latest maven (verified on version 3.6.3)
- add those parameters

```sh
mvn clean package -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true
```

Comment: This command is life saving. Thank you very much

Comment: very nice solurion. Thanx @justin

Answer (score 2):

I get this problem when my JRE does not have the correct certificate to get through my companies proxy and out to the repo.

**Step 1** will depend on your IT department. You'll need to find the **.crt** file that gets you through your https proxy, and download it as Your_Proxy.crt

**Step 2** is running "mvn -version" to make 100% sure you know which JRE your maven is using.

**Step 3** is going to the JRE folder in an administrator mode using Powershell on windows or sudo on linux and

```
./bin/keytool.exe -importcert -ckeystore cacerts -file Your_Proxy.crt -alias Add_name_here
```

... you will need to know your keystore's password, which often defaults to "changeit"

Answer (score 1):

I know the thread is old. Perhaps this is for the other users who might stumble upon this to find an answer

EM-Creations is right. The use of `http` will result in the default redirection to `https`. I've searched through several stackoverflow questions and other sites and the right answer would be to somehow make maven trust the certifcate of the repository/url/site that we wanted to work with

For that first we need to import the (root) certificate of that part site. Please follow this link
https://www.comodo.com/support/products/authentication_certs/setup/mac_chrome.php

Now maven by default uses the java keystore trusted certificates and by default the trusted certificates are at `{JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib.security/cacerts`. So the next step is to add our downloaded certificate  to the cacerts. For this you can use either the openssl or keytool commands. I prefer keytool personally and  here is a sample one

```
keytool 
-import 
-storepass <STOREPASS_PASSWORD> 
-noprompt 
-alias < unique  certificate alias for Keystore> 
-keystore <JRE_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts 
-trustcacerts 
-file <certificate file>
```

for mac users the default execution will result in a permission denied error. So you can use `sudo` to make it executable and writable

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I ran `mvn clean install` and for me the solution turned out to be very different...

I had an entry in my maven's `settings.xml` file for proxy like:

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    ... 
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

I tried importing the certs to my cacerts and all, but those did not help.

Only after I removed the above proxy entry, it worked. (possibly the proxy settings changed in our corporate and so the above setting I had from some time back became invalid)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a repository other than apache maven repository, try to use `http` instead of `https` in the url.

Comment: Often the server will force it back to HTTPS regardless.

Comment: How to avoid it? I mean server forcing it to HTTPS

Comment: @AkshayJoshi In `<mirror><url>...</url></mirror>` specify url with `http`, but if it redirect to `https`, then this won't work.

Comment: Thanks Eric.. in my case the problem was, there was a <repositories> tag used in pom.xml which was overriding the configuration done in settings.xml. Removing that repositories tag from pom.xml solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this error after switching to a new JDK.

My company has a nexus mirror for maven central. My maven is configured to this repo (so to have both internal and public dependencies).

I didn't have the company `cacerts` file under `<java home>/lib/security/`.

Adding this file solved the problem.