# Java Keystore unable to add X509Certificate to Keystore

Tags: java, spring-boot, x509certificate, keystore

I am facing a weird error when I try to add a certificate to Keystore.

```
System.out.println(x509Certificate.getPublicKey()); // prints public key, certificate is valid
GlobalStoreManager.getInstance().getSPATruststore().setCertificateEntry(name, x509Certificate); // no error
System.out.println(GlobalStoreManager.getInstance().getSPATruststore().getCertificate(name)); // null
```

Why is the `setCertificateEntry` is not throwing any error and still  `getCertificate` returns null?

**Update:**

I tried to get the certificate alias right after calling `setCertificateEntry()` and it worked??!, so the problems seems to be with `getCertificate()` call rather than `setCertificateEntry()` call?

```
System.out.println(GlobalStoreManager.getInstance().getSPATruststore().getCertificateAlias(x509Certificate));
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is your key bit size ?

Comment: @Rookie007 2048

Comment: @Rookie007 please see my update also

Comment: Did install the certificate in ur machine

Comment: @SapneshNaik Okay may be this is not the reason, its always better to check, whether your java has bit size more than `256` or not. because when you are trying to set the certificate its not even getting set, so its always `null`

Comment: You're probably getting two different instances of the `keyStore`, and as you haven't saved the first one the second one doesn't see the update.

Comment: @user207421, I checked for that too and can confirm both objects are of same reference

Comment: @SapneshNaik, did you store the keystore after `GlobalStoreManager.getInstance().getSPATruststore().setCertificateEntry`? `setCertificateEntry` is not persistent. You would need something similtar to `getSPATruststore().store(out, password);`

Comment: @pedrofb I am only using a in memory keystore, I can not save it to any file

Comment: I have tested your code using an empty keystore and a sample x509certificate and it works perfectly. Look for the error in the keystore implementation that returns `GlobalStoreManager.getInstance().getSPATruststore()`

Comment: try to check your java certificate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using/8980479
then replace your cacerts file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the alias in setCertificateEntry(). Try it with keytool.