# Can you help me to fix the connection with my DBeaver?

Tags: mysql, database, localhost, dbeaver

I have this message in my DBeaver
Can you help me to fix the problem?

```
Network error

Motif:

Network unavailable:

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Comment: This is the first time I'm using windows11 and the first time I've seen this. Wondering if win11 forced the security default.

Answer (score 23):

I have similar error the first time that i open a DB:

> Network error
>
> Reason: Network unavailable due to certificate issue. Try changing the
> setting `Use Windows trust store` in Preferences->Connections and
> restart DBeaver. It might help if you haven't overridden trust store.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

I try 'bAsK' solution but not work for me.

The solution for me is remove check in the setting `Use Windows trust store` in Preferences->Connections and restart DBeaver

[image]

I also installed JRE 8 (Java)

Answer (score 10):

On Windows:

In DBeaver installation path, open the dbeaver.ini file and remove this line: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31733413)

Comment: And indeed, the link is no longer valid.

Comment: @RobertAltman I've added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76389734/4549619) with the steps from the link.

Answer (score 10):

**For macOS:**

Edit:

`/Applications/DBeaver.app/Contents/Eclipse/dbeaver.ini`

add the line:

`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=KeychainStore`

Restart the DBeaver application to resolve this problem.

Comment: I believe this comment is from the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4341
For what it's worth, this fix did not work for me on MacOS

Comment: This will work for mac too!

Comment: After  applying this now getting:

Network unavailable
java.net.SocketException:java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)
Network unavailable
java.net.SocketException:java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext)

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this using below option enabled.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using custom cacerts in your Java installation you need to [replace the cacerts file in DBeaver's jre folder](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Importing-CA-Certificates-into-DBeaver/22.2/).
The jre folder is located in the main installation folder of DBeaver.

Note that if someone installed your Java for you (e.g. on a company machine) you might be not aware that Java cacerts where updated, so this solution might be also worth trying.
In such case copy the cacerts file from /lib/security folder of your Java installation into jre folder of DBeaver (see also [How do I find out what keystore my JVM is using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980364/how-do-i-find-out-what-keystore-my-jvm-is-using)).

Answer (score -1):

I did the same step, and did not work, but then I changed the SSL Factory to org.postgresql.ssl.LibPQFactory and it works.