# DBeaver - unable to update driver: "Network unavailable due to certificate issue."

Tags: ssl, networking, ssl-certificate, driver, dbeaver

Always getting this error when I try to update my PostgreSql driver.

I found few StackOverflow questions about it but all solutions seems outdated and/or does not works for the most recent version of DBeaver 23.0.1. Many references to "java..." string in ".ini" are just not there.

The error:

> Network error
>
> Reason: Network unavailable due to certificate issue. Try changing the
> setting `Use Windows trust store` in Preferences->Connections and
> restart DBeaver. It might help if you haven't overridden trust store.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:PKIX path building failed:
> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
> find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: where you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure 100% but it works well now. I re-install a newer version and I think it was working fine. It is also possible that is cause becuase our company is using a proxy which impersonify (the proxy simulate another person). The application detects the security issue due to impersonification (proxy) and prevent the installation/update. I think we need to install a certificate in order to make i works fine but I didn't do it. Another solution for the proxy is at the firewall, they let DBeaver pass directly (wihtout proxy). I think our security team did it (passthrough for DBeaver ).

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178184/6505847

Comment: @AzyCrw4282, That's sound good!!! I do not have the problem anymore but can you write an answer with you link and I will accept it. It sounds like being the actual best workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178184/6505847) first. Option 1 should normally fix it.

If it still doesn't work then try installing a newer version if you are on an old one.

It is also possible to be blocked by a proxy. In such case, you would need to add a valid `.crt` file. Depending on the proxy, generate a `.crt` file ( should be fine with `.pem` type) and then add the file to the relevant directory (e.g.,
`/etc/ssl/certs/<crt>`
).
save and restart should fix the proxy issue.