# How to find JDK directory in Ubuntu for JNI C/C++ library

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, jvm, java-native-interface

I am trying to use JNI for my recent project. MY IDE is NetBeans. After creating C/C++ project , I am trying to add JDK directory from project properties->C compiler->include directory.
I could not find any include or include/linux directory in /usr/lib/jvm/ directory.

Where should i look for "include" or "include/linux" directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find the Java SDK in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251323/where-can-i-find-the-java-sdk-in-linux)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Assuming you've got a JDK installed the directory should be something like: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` (assuming OpenJDK 7 here). You might also need to a `JAVA_HOME` environment variable pointing at the same directory depending on your build process.

If you haven't got a JDK installed you can install the OpenJDK with something like the following in a terminal windows:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Comment: For 32 bits it's /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386.

Comment: I am confused, is this where the "include" directory is supposed to be?