# Netbeans not opening in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, netbeans-7

I have installed NetBeans 8 in /opt folder due to permission reasons. I created a symlink and worked in my local from the morning. Suddenly, now it's not opening. IT does not seem to be crashed but I don't know why.

Any suggestions please

Comment: Please specify something more,it won't be resolved with only this much of hint!

Comment: I mean i have the netbeans installed in /opt folder. But it's not opening

Comment: How it's not opening? Means the start-up screen just freezes OR some permission related error is being thrown OR some other reason is being displayed? Please clarify a bit more!!!

Comment: How did you install it? Try uninstalling it with `--purge` and then install it thru the repository with `apt-get`. I'm using Ubuntu 14 and NB 8 and it works for me.

Comment: I don't have idea about how it is installed since i don't have administartive privileges... so i cant do the sudor any other terminal commands.. am helpless

Comment: Please run from terminal and check the output.

Answer (score 8):

First:

```
sudo apt autoremove netbeans
```

Download netbeans 8.2 from:
https://netbeans.org/

after you download the file, go to the directory and:

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
cd Downloads
```

or wherever the script netbeans-8.2-linux.sh is. Then

```
sudo chmod +x netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

Follow the instructions. If the field for JDK is empty, reinstall it, and then run the script again.
You can remove JDK 8 too. This is not necessary, up to you.

Answer (score 4):

Check the path for `netbeans_jdkhome` in `netbeans.conf`. 
You can find this file at usr/local/netbeans 8.2/etc/netbeans.conf`.

In `netbeans.conf` see this

```
netbeans_jdkhome="path_to_java"
```

for example:
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64"
or
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
If `path_to_java` is incorrect, replace it with your actual java path.
check your actual path by using $JAVA_HOME and copy it.
**Note** this path is without `/bin` directory, so don't include `/bin` at the end of the path.

Comment: and how do i find, where is my default JDK installed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251323/where-can-i-find-the-java-sdk-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

Download [netbeans with jdk for linux](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-netbeans-jsp-3413139-esa.html)
and after the download run these commands for install:

```
/Downloads# chmod +x jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh
/Downloads# ./jdk-8u111-nb-8_2-linux-x64.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install --reinstall netbeans will solve your issue. you must be running a situation where netbeans is older than your jdk or have some modules that are failing to start or have missing licences.
start the ide from console [type netbeans], possibly there are modules which are failing and you may be presented with an option to close those modules and continue. After that you can then update your modules or best disable those you do not use.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have installed an older version of netbeans and your JDK is latest. Make sure that you install a latest version of netbeans which is supported by your JDK.

Happy Coding!

Comment: That is just one of the cases. What about latest all?

Comment: Then you need to configure your path variables correctly.

Comment: It was a corrupted netbeans comfig in my case

Answer (score 0):

this got it working for me:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vajdics/netbeans-installer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install netbeans-installer
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me as well after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04. Netbeans stopped working. I tried many ways changing the configuration.

The primary reason for this problem is java dependency.

Netbeans is directly dependent on Oracle Java and has tight coupling. Ubuntu 18.04 comes with default open jdk11 installed and set as default java.

When Netbeans starts it checks for the dependencies and fails due `OpenJDK`. Though in few cases it opens but not every features working. Sometime only few windows only opens in the IDE. Specially project explorer doesn't work.

To see the errors you can check the log file from the `menu->view->IDELog`

`System Info: 
  Product Version         = NetBeans IDE 8.2 (Build 201609300101) (#5fd841261bf9)
  Operating System        = Linux version 4.15.0-34-generic running on amd64
  Java; VM; Vendor        = 1.8.0_181; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13; Oracle Corporation
  Runtime                 = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_181-b13
  Java Home               = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
  System Locale; Encoding = en_IN (nb); UTF-8
  Home Directory          = /home/mukesh
  Current Directory       = /home/mukesh
  User Directory          = /home/mukesh/.netbeans/8.2
  Cache Directory         = /home/mukesh/.cache/netbeans/8.2
  Installation            = /home/mukesh/netbeans-8.2/...`

------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

Finally what worked for me is.

Finally what worked for me is setting the `java_home` path in the installed directory of Netbeans. Netbeans 8.2 is installed in HOME directory in general. Sometime it can be different. You can find out using `locate` command. change path for java_home inside

`/home/<Netbean DIR>/etc/netbeans.conf
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"`

Restart the Netbeans and it will work all well.

**NOTE: Changing the above in system `/etc/netbeans.conf` directory will not work.**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too after upgrading to Ubunutu 18.04 from 16.04.

This worked for me.

**Install Oracle 8 JDK**

Got the instructions from here:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/05/install-oracle-java-jdk-8-10-ubuntu-18-04/

```
add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

**Configure Netbeans**

Edit the netbeans.conf files to point to the Oracle 8 Java.

```
find / -name netbeans.conf -print 2>/dev/null
```

In my case this returned:

```
/usr/share/netbeans/8.1/etc/netbeans.conf 
/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/etc/netbeans.conf 
/etc/netbeans.conf
```

For each netbeans.conf returned edit the file to set the `netbeans_jdkhome` to the Oracle Java.

```
netbeans_jdkhome="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"
```

**Re-Install Netbeans**

This still didn't work .. both 8.1. and 8.2 netbeans would crash out on the splash screen whun it got to "Loading modules".

So, I then re-installed Netbeans from the downloaded installer:

```
wget -c http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.2/final/bundles/netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
bash ./netbeans-8.2-linux.sh
```

Then, running the 8.2 netbeans `/usr/local/netbeans-8.2/bin/netbeans` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue by deleting all NetBeans related config files in home directory.
I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you copied over your installation from another computer, try to remove `<NetBeans-8.2 installation directory>/nb/var/cache` directory.