# Unable to find where my java installation is

Tags: java, linux

I have java installed. However, `JAVA_HOME` is empty and I can't find out where it should point to:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java': No such file or directory

$ ls /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681090/how-do-i-find-where-jdk-is-installed-on-my-windows-machine) might help you. On unix based system `which java` should work

Comment: you should look for this in linux forums: e.g. [Where can I find the Java SDK in Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5251365/6287240)

Comment: Please also try : `$ find /usr/ -name "java*"` and `$ find /etc/alternatives/ -name java`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
which java | xargs -L1 ls -al
```

it will show you where `java` is really stored on your hard drive as it must a symbolic link

**An example of Output:**

```
/usr/bin/java -> /foo/bar/java
```

In this case `java` is in the directory `bar`

Comment: `which` will work if java is in the PATH (which normally it would be). However java may have been installed in a custom location. Also, Java is often installed peculiarly so you may get `/usr/java/default/bin/java` which is **another** link and not where JAVA_HOME should point.

This works for many Linux installations:  `find /usr/java -wholename '*ava/jdk*' -prune`